# R/Shiny Dataframe Columns

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with Shiny, and i have another question, hopefully much easier:

I have a dataframe (uploaded from a CSV), where I want the user to select a Dependent variable, and then select their independent variables, but the list of available columns for the IV selection should now not include the dependent variable that they just selected.

I've been staring and reactive expressions all day, and have no clue.  It's probably really obvious too.
Any help would be great.

Here is a code snippet from the Server code

```
# Read file ----
df <- reactive({
 req(input$uploaded_file)
 read.csv(input$uploaded_file$datapath,
         header = input$header,
         sep = input$sep)  

 })


# dynamically allow the user to select a dependent variable ----
  output$selectbox <- renderUI({
  selectInput(inputId = "select_dev", 
            label = "Select target variable", 
            choices = names(df()))
})

# Dynamically allow the user to select their independent variables using checkboxes ----
###
###  Here is where I would like to remove the variable from the DF that they selected in output$selectbox. 
###
  output$checkbox <- renderUI({
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select_var", 
                   label = "Select variables", 
                   choices = names(df()),
                   selected = names(df()))
})
```

Perhaps there is an easier way than this to manipulate a reactive function.  The goal is to have  dataframe that I can treat as a set of independent variables, and be able to call on it for multiple analyses.

Comment: I can help you but first you need to update your post with a small working example.

Comment: just updated.  Thank you!  Please let me know if you need additional code snippets.  As I am just learning, I'm sure my code is not optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go -

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    uiOutput("selectbox"),
    uiOutput("checkbox")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    df <- reactive(iris)

    output$selectbox <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = "select_dev", 
                  label = "Select target variable", 
                  choices = names(df()))
    })

    output$checkbox <- renderUI({
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select_var", 
                         label = "Select variables", 
                         choices = setdiff(names(df()), input$select_dev),
                         selected = setdiff(names(df()), input$select_dev))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Shree - thank you for your assistance - any chance you could take a look at a follow-up question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643105/shiny-r-unable-to-rename-column-headers